# HBase table creation issue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-ranger

I've been exploring HBase in my HDP cluster; facing an issue with table creation.

I can create a table called 'test':

```
hbase(main):002:0> create 'test','cf1','cf2'
0 row(s) in 1.2300 seconds

=> Hbase::Table - test
```

But when I try some other table creation, I couldn't. Example:

```
hbase(main):005:0> create 'employee','personal','professional'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions for user 'user22349@mail.co.in' (action=create)
```

The cluster is kerberized and Ranger is active. I've had to add my user's permissions earlier in Ranger to even get the 'test' table created.

If it can create a table named 'test', why it can't create any other table per se? Any clues?

Comment: Does the test table already exist?

Comment: Before creating the test table, no. It doesn't.